# Calculate runtime per row over multiple rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My dataset looks like this: (First three columns are Input, I added columns 4-6, the last column represents the desired output)

```
+-------------------+------+----+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---+----+
|          timestamp|status| msg|      end_timestamp|          start_eng|           stop_eng| --|res |
+-------------------+------+----+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---+----+
|2017-01-01 06:15:00| ASC_a|nice|2017-01-01 07:00:00|               null|               null|-->|  0 |
|2017-01-01 07:00:00| ASC_a|nice|2017-01-01 07:15:00|               null|               null|-->|  0 |
|2017-01-01 07:15:00| start|nice|2017-01-01 08:00:00|2017-01-01 07:15:00|               null|-->| 45 |
|2017-01-01 08:00:00| start|nice|2017-01-01 08:22:00|2017-01-01 08:00:00|               null|-->| 22 |
|2017-01-01 08:22:00| ASC_b|init|2017-01-01 09:00:00|               null|               null|-->| 38 |
|2017-01-01 09:00:00| ASC_b|init|2017-01-01 09:30:00|               null|               null|-->| 30 |
|2017-01-01 09:30:00|   end| bla|2017-01-01 10:00:00|               null|2017-01-01 09:30:00|-->|  0 |
|2017-01-01 10:00:00|   end| bla|2017-01-01 10:45:00|               null|2017-01-01 10:00:00|-->|  0 |
|2017-01-01 10:45:00| ASC_a|meas|2017-01-01 11:00:00|               null|               null|-->|  0 |
|2017-01-01 11:00:00| ASC_a|meas|2017-01-01 12:00:00|               null|               null|-->|  0 |
|2017-01-01 12:00:00| ASC_a|meas|2017-01-01 12:15:00|               null|               null|-->|  0 |
|2017-01-01 12:15:00| start|meas|2017-01-01 13:00:00|2017-01-01 12:15:00|               null|-->| 45 |
|2017-01-01 13:00:00| start|meas|2017-01-01 13:22:00|2017-01-01 13:00:00|               null|-->| 22 |
|2017-01-01 13:22:00| ASC_c|init|2017-01-01 14:00:00|               null|               null|-->| 38 |
|2017-01-01 14:00:00| ASC_c|init|2017-01-01 14:31:00|               null|               null|-->| 31 |
|2017-01-01 14:31:00|   end|meas|               null|               null|2017-01-01 14:31:00|-->|  0 |
+-------------------+------+----+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---+----+
```

I want to calculate the engine runtime from the first occurence of status start to the first occurence of status end. (the statuses start and end are present in subsequent columns because I added rows with the explode function, I just still have to change them to a reasonable value later)

The problem is I have no idea how to calculate the engine runtime for the rows between start and end which contain neither start nor end.
I thought about using a window function for the calculation but I just don't know how to specify the window for this.

Comment: can you also share the codes you've tried so far?

Comment: the problem that spark rdd is full distributed and you can find the `start`, between rows and `end` in differents partitions, you can't have a specific key field for all line between start and end ?

Comment: If I find a way to get rid of the duplicate start end end entries and fill their status with the last ASC status I think I could do it almost exactly the same way I did it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45815464/correct-way-to-fill-dataset-with-data-based-on-window.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work for the small dataset. Still have to test it on the big one.

```
//get tempstat column
    val ds3 = ds2.withColumn("tempstat", when($"status".contains("ASC"), $"status").otherwise(null))
      .withColumn("tempstat_final", last($"tempstat", true).over(window))

    //remove duplicate status
    val ds5 = ds3.withColumn("new_status", when(!$"status".contains("ASC") && lag($"status", 1).over(window) =!= $"status", $"status").otherwise($"tempstat_final"))

    //get column that provides window for calculation
    val ds6 = ds5.withColumn("startFlag", when($"new_status" === "start", 1).otherwise(0))
        .withColumn("stopFlag", when($"new_status" === "end", -1).otherwise(0))
        .withColumn("bothFlags", $"startFlag" + $"stopFlag")
      .withColumn("engineFlag", sum($"bothFlags").over(Window.orderBy("timestamp")))

    //calculate runtime
    val ds7 = ds6.withColumn("runtime", when($"engineFlag" === 1,
      ((unix_timestamp(lead($"timestamp", 1).over(Window.orderBy($"timestamp"))) - unix_timestamp($"timestamp"))/60)
    ).otherwise(lit(0)))
```

Output and progression looks as follows.

```
+-------------------+------+----+--------+--------------+----------+---------+--------+---------+----------+-------+
|          timestamp|status| msg|tempstat|tempstat_final|new_status|startFlag|stopFlag|bothFlags|engineFlag|runtime|
+-------------------+------+----+--------+--------------+----------+---------+--------+---------+----------+-------+
|2017-01-01 06:15:00| ASC_a|nice|   ASC_a|         ASC_a|     ASC_a|        0|       0|        0|         0|    0.0|
|2017-01-01 07:00:00| ASC_a|nice|   ASC_a|         ASC_a|     ASC_a|        0|       0|        0|         0|    0.0|
|2017-01-01 07:15:00| start|nice|    null|         ASC_a|     start|        1|       0|        1|         1|   45.0|
|2017-01-01 08:00:00| start|nice|    null|         ASC_a|     ASC_a|        0|       0|        0|         1|   22.0|
|2017-01-01 08:22:00| ASC_b|init|   ASC_b|         ASC_b|     ASC_b|        0|       0|        0|         1|   38.0|
|2017-01-01 09:00:00| ASC_b|init|   ASC_b|         ASC_b|     ASC_b|        0|       0|        0|         1|   30.0|
|2017-01-01 09:30:00|   end| bla|    null|         ASC_b|       end|        0|      -1|       -1|         0|    0.0|
|2017-01-01 10:00:00|   end| bla|    null|         ASC_b|     ASC_b|        0|       0|        0|         0|    0.0|
|2017-01-01 10:45:00| ASC_a|meas|   ASC_a|         ASC_a|     ASC_a|        0|       0|        0|         0|    0.0|
|2017-01-01 11:00:00| ASC_a|meas|   ASC_a|         ASC_a|     ASC_a|        0|       0|        0|         0|    0.0|
|2017-01-01 12:00:00| ASC_a|meas|   ASC_a|         ASC_a|     ASC_a|        0|       0|        0|         0|    0.0|
|2017-01-01 12:15:00| start|meas|    null|         ASC_a|     start|        1|       0|        1|         1|   45.0|
|2017-01-01 13:00:00| start|meas|    null|         ASC_a|     ASC_a|        0|       0|        0|         1|   60.0|
|2017-01-01 14:00:00| start|meas|    null|         ASC_a|     ASC_a|        0|       0|        0|         1|   60.0|
|2017-01-01 15:00:00| start|meas|    null|         ASC_a|     ASC_a|        0|       0|        0|         1|   22.0|
|2017-01-01 15:22:00| ASC_c|init|   ASC_c|         ASC_c|     ASC_c|        0|       0|        0|         1|   38.0|
|2017-01-01 16:00:00| ASC_c|init|   ASC_c|         ASC_c|     ASC_c|        0|       0|        0|         1|   31.0|
|2017-01-01 16:31:00|   end|meas|    null|         ASC_c|       end|        0|      -1|       -1|         0|    0.0|
+-------------------+------+----+--------+--------------+----------+---------+--------+---------+----------+-------++
```

I am always happy to get tips for improvement or other solution proposals since I am still new to spark / scala.